# Blocking a number through my app

Tags: android, phone-call, callblocking

Currently i am working on a call block app. And after completion of app i found a bug :- Suppose i am blocking contact of Person A having number "9806584545" but when Person A calls me,his number shows with ISD code and because of which number is not block. So to block phone number of Person A, i need to save his contact with ISD code and then block the number,then only it will work. Please someone help me. Here is my code below :-

BlockedContactAdapter.java :-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.rsoft.callblocker.R;
import com.rsoft.notificationCenter.CallBlockerToastNotification;
import com.rsoft.objects.BlockedContact;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BlockedContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
   private Activity activity;
   private ArrayList<BlockedContact>contacts;

public BlockedContactAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<BlockedContact>contacts)
{
    this.activity=activity;
    this.contacts=contacts;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{

    return contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{

    return contacts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blacklist_layout, null);
    }

    final BlockedContact cn=contacts.get(position);

    TextView name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.blacklistNameTxt);
    TextView number=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.blacklistNumberTxt);

    name.setText(cn.getName());
    number.setText(cn.getNumber());

    /*if(cn.getNumber().length() == 10) {
        num = country_code.concat(cn.getNumber());
    } else if (cn.getNumber().length() <= 10) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Invalid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        num = cn.getNumber();
    }

    number.setText(num);*/

    final ImageButton callButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.blacklistCallButton);
    final ImageButton smsButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.blacklistSmsButton);
    final ImageButton deleteButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.blacklistDeleteButton);

    if(cn.isBlockedForCalling())
    {
        callButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.phonered);
    }
    if(cn.isBlockedForMessages())
    {
        smsButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.smsred);
    }

    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(cn.isBlockedForCalling() )
            {
                cn.setBlockedForCalling(false);
                callButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.phoneblack);
                CallBlockerToastNotification.showDefaultShortNotification(cn.getName() + " can call you");
            }
            else
            {
                cn.setBlockedForCalling(true);
                callButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.phonered);
                CallBlockerToastNotification.showDefaultShortNotification(cn.getName()+" can not call you");
            }
        }
    });

    smsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(cn.isBlockedForMessages())
            {
                cn.setBlockedForMessages(false);
                smsButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.smsblack);
                CallBlockerToastNotification.showDefaultShortNotification(cn.getName()+" can text you");
            }
            else
            {
                cn.setBlockedForMessages(true);
                smsButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.smsred);
                CallBlockerToastNotification.showDefaultShortNotification(cn.getName()+" can not text you");
            }
        }
    });

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            AlertDialog dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
            dialog.setTitle("Delete contact");
            dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this contact from blacklist?");
            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes" ,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    CallBlockerMainActivity.blackList.remove(cn.getNumber());
                    CallBlockerBlacklistViewActivity.updateListData();
                }
            });
            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {

                }
            });
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.advert);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    return vi;
}

}
```

DeviceStateListener :-

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;
import com.rsoft.callBlockerService.CallBlockerService;
import com.rsoft.objects.BlockedContact;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

    public class DeviceStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
   {
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
    private Context context;

public DeviceStateListener(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
    initializeTelephonyService();
}

private void initializeTelephonyService()
{
    try
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Class clase=Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
        Method method=clase.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService=(ITelephony)method.invoke(telephonyManager);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) 
{
    switch(state)
    {

    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

        final BlockedContact cn=CallBlockerService.blackList.get(incomingNumber);
        if(cn!=null && cn.isBlockedForCalling())
        {
            try
            {
                telephonyService.endCall();
                Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss");
                        Date date=new Date();
                        String currentDate=dateFormat.format(date);

                        //LOG FORMAT --> TITLE;;MESSAGE;;NAME;;NUMBER;;HOUR;;BODYMESSAGE(NULL);;SEPARATOR
                        String message="Call Blocked;;A call from "+cn.getName()+" ("+incomingNumber+") was blocked at "+currentDate+";;"+cn.getName()+";;"+incomingNumber+";;"+currentDate+";;NULL;;\r\n";
                        writeInLog(message);
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            } 
            catch (RemoteException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

public void writeInLog(String message)
{
    try
    {
        OutputStreamWriter fos = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("CallLog.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
        fos.append(message);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Writed in log succesfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Why don't you store all the blocked number in a local file or DB?

Comment: will this solve my problem?